# Extending ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I want to extend ScrollViewer to add some Dependency Properties in order to use Storyboard to animate Horizontal and Vertical Offsets as shown here: [How do I add an extended class ScrollViewer to the XAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672465/how-do-i-add-an-extended-class-scrollviewer-to-the-xaml-file)

It happens that ScrollViewer class is sealed.

Is there any workaround to accomplish my goal?

Comment: are you sure it is sealed? msdn don't show that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, don't know why but it seems it is sealed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209527 Your link is valid for WPF. It's also sealed for Silverlight

Comment: I don't see sealed in IlSpy too.

Comment: It's sealed as you can see in this screenshot http://imageshack.com/a/img843/8403/ecp0.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot research I found a clean solution for my problem. And it's called attached dependency property. You can see in http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.pt/2010/05/attached-dependency-properties-for.html how to create it.

After that it was pretty straight to use that dependency property with storyboard to create my smooth scrollviewer.